# How to do an action after a user cancels a request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

After a user cancels a delete confirmation I want to fire a javascript call to stopPropagation  on the element. I cant do this on click because it will then prevent the showing of the JS confirmation dialog. Is there a way to bind an action to when the user cancels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete")){
  // user has chosen 'Ok'
} else {
  // user has canceled
  // do your stuff
}
```